# Form input template does not save

Tags: django, python-2.7

py in a def that lists me articles in a table, which have the inputtext of my model forms, RequestEditForm, input that appear next to each article, plus a button which saves the amount of inpuText saved. My problem is that the button does nothing, so it does not save in the database the amounts entered.

```
    def ListAll(request, id_especialidad):
       especialidad = Especialidad.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)
    if request.method == 'GET':
      user = request.user
    if user.is_superuser:
       pedido = Pedido.objects.filter(especialidad=especialidad)
       form = PedidoEditForm()
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
      pedido.estado = 'pendiente'
      pedido.fecha_pedido = datetime.now()
      pedido.save()
```

return render(request, 'admindata.html', locals(),{'form':form})

```
      <section id="contenido">
     <div class="container" style="margin:50px auto width="100%"">
    <form id="myform" method="post">
    <table id="example" class="table table-border table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <td>Servicio</td>
                <td>Cod experto</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>stock</td>
                <td>Cantidad</td>
                <td>Fecha Pedido</td>
                <td>Estado</td>
                <td>Ingresar</td>
                <td></td>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Servicio</td>
                <td>Cod experto</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>stock</td>
                <td>Cantidad</td>
                <td>Fecha Pedido</td>
                <td>Estado</td>
                <td></td> 

            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
    {% if pedido  %}
    {% for ped in pedido  %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ped.especialidad.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ ped.articulo.cod_experto }}</td>
                <td>{{ ped.articulo.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ ped.articulo.stock }}</td>
                <td>{{ ped.cantidad }}</td>
                <td>{{ ped.fecha_pedido }}</td>
                <td>{{ ped.estado }}</td>
                <td>{% csrf_token %}
                    {{form.as_p}}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
       </tbody>
       </table>
       </form>

</div>
</section>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/jquery.form.min.js" %}"></script>


<script>
 $(document).ready(function (){
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({

  'columnDefs': [
     {
        'targets': 0,
     }
  ],
  });

  table.column(7).every( function () {

  var column = this;
   var select = $('<input type="submit" form="myform" class= "btn btn-      success" value="Guardar">')
  .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
  .on('change', function() {
    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
      $(this).val()
    );

    column
      .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
      .draw();
  });

column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
  select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
});

});

});
```

Because the button does not work, which I lack also I have the error of:
UserWarning:

```
       A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not    provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
     " A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context " help me pls!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `render_to_respoonse` use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) like this:

```
return render(request, template, locals())
```

Also you have a `submit` button outside of the form!

You should either put it inside the `<form></form>` or define in the `<input>` the [id of the form where it belongs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp). Like this:

```
<input type="submit" form="myform" class= "btn btn-success" value="Guardar">
```

Comment: I still can not get myself to add

Comment: And that means?

Comment: And the <td> {% csrf_token%}
                {{Form.as_p}} </ td>
            </ Tr>
At the end of the table does not work the same way?

Comment: Updated once more!

Comment: Thanks for the help sir, I do not know what a past but now I do not think the button wherever I put it in html: /

Comment: Sorry, now the button does not appear on the page, I do not know what happened, update the html!

Comment: Maybe you should enter it inside a `<td></td>` ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you said (once more!).

Comment: Excuse me, I do not handle English! XD

Comment: Sir I'm still at this, and the button does not work to add only valid fields that are not empty, and when the fields are completed it does nothing, could you help me, dear?

Comment: No tira errores, simplemente no funciona el botón de no realizar la acción add: c  button no action!

Comment: So, the problem to your posted question has been solved! The matter that your button does not behave like you want it to, is another question. I suggest to open a new question with this issue. If my answer helped you, marked it as accepted!